# compact switch statement that uses repeatedly same templated function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following C++ code with a fairly big switch statement (I am using a C++11 compiler):

```
void function(std::size_t i, other_args)
{
   switch(i)
   {
      case 0:
         templatedfunction<0>(other_args);
         break;
      case 1:
         templatedfunction<1>(other_args);
         break;
      case 2:
         templatedfunction<2>(other_args);
         break;
      ...............
      //lots of other cases here
      ...............
      case 100:
         templatedfunction<100>(other_args);
         break;

   }  

}
```

where `templatedfunction` is defined as

```
template<std::size_t T>
void templatedfunction(other_args){
   //some code here
}
```

This is a lot of lines of code for describing a simple concept (i.e., call `templatedfunction` with the same value as variable `i` passed in its templated parameter). Is there a way in C++ to write this code more compactly? There should be a way to implement this long switch statement more compactly....Using `templatedfunction<i>(other_args)` will not compile since `i` is a variable and not a compile time constant. Thanks.

Comment: You could build an array of `templatedfunction<0>` through `templatedfunction<N>` (possibly with a generator or a fun bit of Static Table Generation) and then replace the function with `funcarray[i](other_args);`

Comment: Is it intentional to have no `break;`s after each function call?

Comment: no, there should be a break after each function call

Answer (score 6):

Non recursive approach would be to create array of function pointers and then select one based on index.

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
void function_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t i)
{
    using func_t = void(*)();
    static constexpr std::array<func_t, sizeof...(Is)> fnc_arr = {
        (&templatedfunction<Is>)...
    };

    fnc_arr[i]();
}

void function(std::size_t i)
{
    function_impl(std::make_index_sequence<100>(), i);
}
```

See it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/803a4d8ebc493f13).
Note that `std::index_sequence` is C++14, but can be easily implemented in C++11.

### EDIT:

Here is a simple implementation of `index_sequence`. Note that it is very poor implementation as it's recursive and the depth is O(N), so it won't let you do `make_index_sequence<5000>` you can google better implementation. Also it's just `index` not `integer` sequence.

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence
{
    using type = std::size_t;

    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
    {
        return sizeof...(Is);
    }
};

namespace detail
{
    template<std::size_t N, typename Seq>
    struct append;

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
    struct append<N, index_sequence<Is...>>
    {
        using type = index_sequence<Is..., N>;
    };


    template<std::size_t N>
    struct make_integer_seq
    {
        using type = typename append<N, typename make_integer_seq<N - 1>::type>::type;
    };

    template<>
    struct make_integer_seq<0>
    {
        using type = index_sequence<0>;
    };
}

template<std::size_t N>
using make_integer_sequence = typename detail::make_integer_seq<N - 1>::type;
```

Comment: is there a simple way of doing std::index_sequence in C++11? It is not obvious to me. Thanks

Comment: @astrophobia I've edited my answer and added implementation of `index_sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
template<std::size_t> struct Index_t { };

template<std::size_t i, class... Ts>
void function_impl(std::size_t index, Index_t<i>, const Ts&... ts)
{
    if (index == i)
        templatedfunction<i>(ts...);
    else
        function_impl(index, Index_t<i + 1>{}, ts...);
}

template<class... Ts>
void function_impl(std::size_t, Index_t<101>, const Ts&...)
{ }

template<class... Ts>
void function(std::size_t index, const Ts&... ts)
{ 
    function_impl(index, Index_t<0>{}, ts...);
}
```

An optimizer is highly likely to transform all these recursive calls into a bunch of compare and jump assembly instructions. A simple example is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/mATCvV).

(In the code above I assumed that your `switch` cases do not fall through.)

Comment: That's great, a perfect replication of the asker's `switch`. I think we can do better with a look-up table, but that's not really what they asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I like the Evg's solution (+1) but is linear, do a lot of template recursion that can exceed the recursion limit (maybe the optimizer can avoid this but I don't like relying on optimizers).

So I propose a logarithmic variation of Evg's solution: we can iterate not over a single index but over a couple of indexes that represent an interval of indexes. And we can split this interval bisecting it according the value of `i`.

I mean: given the following `function()`

```
void function (std::size_t i)
 {
   if ( i > 100 )
      std::cout << i << " is out of range" << std::endl;
   else
      function_impl<0, 101>(i); // as a switch from 0 to 100 (included)
 }
```

we can write the `function_impl()` function as follows

```
template <std::size_t L1, std::size_t L2>
void function_impl (std::size_t i)
 {
   if ( L1 == i )
      templatedFunction<L1>();
   else
    {
      constexpr auto LM { (L1 + L2) >> 1 }; 

      if ( i < LM )
         function_impl<L1, LM>(i);
      else
         function_impl<LM, L2>(i);
    }
 }
```

This heavily reduce the number of recursion calls.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t I>
void templatedFunction ()
 { std::cout << I << std::endl; }

template <std::size_t L1, std::size_t L2>
void function_impl (std::size_t i)
 {
   if ( L1 == i )
      templatedFunction<L1>();
   else
    {
      constexpr auto LM { (L1 + L2) >> 1 }; 

      if ( i < LM )
         function_impl<L1, LM>(i);
      else
         function_impl<LM, L2>(i);
    }

 }

void function (std::size_t i)
 {
   if ( i > 100 )
      std::cout << i << " is out of range" << std::endl;
   else
      function_impl<0, 101>(i);
 }

int main ()
 {
   for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < 102u ; ++ui )
      function(ui);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can change `templatedFunction` so that `i` is an argument rather than a parameter, something tricky should be done.

For instance, preprocessing. A lot has been said on using C++ preprocessor to generate large code sequences ([this one](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic), for instance). Here, to save some typing, if you don't need complicated macro algebra elsewhere, you can go with a simple binary sequence:

```
#define CASE_2(n, CASE) CASE(n); CASE(n + 1)
#define CASE_4(n, CASE) CASE_2(n, CASE); CASE_2(n + 2, CASE)
#define CASE_8(n, CASE) CASE_4(n, CASE); CASE_4(n + 4, CASE)
#define CASE_16(n, CASE) CASE_8(n, CASE); CASE_8(n + 8, CASE)
#define CASE_32(n, CASE) CASE_16(n, CASE); CASE_16(n + 16, CASE)
#define CASE_64(n, CASE) CASE_32(n, CASE); CASE_32(n + 32, CASE)

#define SINGLE_CASE(n) case n: templatedFunction<n>(other_args); break

switch(i) {
    CASE_64(0, SINGLE_CASE);
    CASE_32(64, SINGLE_CASE);
    CASE_4(96, SINGLE_CASE);
    SINGLE_CASE(100);
}
```